# keep checkbox checked after submitting form

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, checkbox

Currently I am able to echo the rows from table according to the checked checkbox name attribute using `isset` in php .

However,  I would like the checkboxes be checked after submitting the form and also if the user **unchecks the checkbox I would like to use the third else statement in the php** where it will retrieve  all rows from the table. How can I achieve this? is it also possible to hide the unchecked box and only show the checked box when a user checks one box. Thanks in advance.

```
<div> Size
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="small" class="checkbox" /> Small
<input type="checkbox" name="medium"  class="checkbox">  Medium<br>
</form> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(function(){
     $('.checkbox').on('change',function(){
        $('#form').submit();
        });
    });
</script>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["small"])){
$paginate = new pagination($page, 'SELECT * FROM pants WHERE size='small' ORDER BY id desc', $options);

}  
else if (isset($_POST["medium"])){
  $paginate = new pagination($page, 'SELECT * FROM pants where size='medium' ORDER BY id desc', $options);
 }
else { $paginate = new pagination($page, 'SELECT * FROM pants ORDER BY id desc', $options);

}
 ?>
```

Comment: Simply check if neither of them are set? `else if (!isset($_POST['small']) && !isset($_POST['medium'])`

Comment: what about keeping it checked then?

Comment: So you want the other one to go away? Why would you do that? Either way, it's trivial to do in jquery.

Comment: You can save the POST values from your form in your database and then pull those values when the form is rendered again. The HTML checked attribute (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp) will be helpful here. This will allow long term saving of form values if that's something you're interested in.

Comment: In a nutshell: `if... condition is met` `<input type="checkbox" name="medium"  class="checkbox" checked>` just a scenario. Not an SQL guy, but you get the general idea ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="small" class="checkbox" <?=(isset($_POST['small'])?' checked':'')?> /> Small
<input type="checkbox" name="medium"  class="checkbox" <?=(isset($_POST['medium'])?' checked':'')?> >  Medium<br>
```

Comment: Is this not what the OP wants?

Comment: I don't know. But this save checkbox status, and if user **unchecks** - then jQuery `.on` triggered too and without any $_POST data work third else statement, as OP want.

Answer (score 0):

This may do the job:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="small" class="checkbox" <?php if ($_POST['small']) echo 'checked'; ?> /> Small
<input type="checkbox" name="medium"  class="checkbox" <?php if ($_POST['medium']) echo 'checked'; ?> />  Medium<br>
```

Comment: Almost identical to the other answer, except you forgot to add `isset`.

Comment: You could just note they were submitted almost at the same time, before you downvote.