# Keep checkbox checked (or) unchecked

Tags: php, html

I'm using XAMPP server & trying to add a simple checkbox into a edit page.
But after submitting & refreshing the page the checkbox
does not stay checked or unchecked

Can someone help me with this

```
<input  id="dating" 
    class="switch"
    type="checkbox" 
    value="1"
    name="dating"
    <?php echo $dating== "1" ? " checked" : ""; ?> >
    <label for="switch"></label>
```

Comment: What is the value of $dating ? did u checked ?

Comment: Post your whole form. Otherwise confirm that you are using POST or GET.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keep checkbox checked after submitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136902/keep-checkbox-checked-after-submitting-form)

Answer (score 0):

You should `var_dump($dating)` to confirm if the statement `$dating== "1"` evaluates the way you intend it to...

Comment: can you give me a full example i don`t understand this

Comment: @mdus2r can you give me a full example ?

Answer (score 0):

use localStorage for it.

**HTML Code:**

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

**JS Code:**

```
$(function(){
    var test = localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false;
    $('input').prop('checked', test || false);
});

$('input').on('change', function() {
    localStorage.input = $(this).is(':checked');
    console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Comment: If i do this & i don`t want to select the checkbox it still stays selected after page re-loading

Comment: if(isset($_POST['dating']) use issest method if form action post

Comment: i trying this but still not working...     <?php

if(isset($_POST["dating"])) {

    // user checked the box

} else {

    // user did not check the box

}

?>

Comment: use local storage instead of this check i have updated answer. Refres js fiddle
 http://jsfiddle.net/CC2hC/1/

Comment: This is overkill. There is no need for JS nor jQ here.

Comment: @laxman thanks for supporting me i did as you said but it is still not working

Comment: what is the issue .can you check the fiddle

Comment: @laxman It still is not working... Question Where can i check the fiddle

Comment: HTML5 is supported by your browser, not your server.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="dating" class="switch" type="checkbox" name="dating" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['dating'])) echo 'checked'; ?> />
```

Comment: After re-loading the page it does not stay checked... & if i don`t want to select it does not stay unselected

Comment: <input id="dating" class="switch" type="checkbox" name="dating" value="1" <?php if($dating =='1') echo 'checked'; ?> />
  <label>Check</label>

Please use this code then

Comment: This will only work if he sends it via POST. If the form is send via GET, you will need to change $_POST to $_GET. Otherwise, you can use $_REQUEST.